# How to make the code "Object Oriented" in order to use the variables inside an ArrayList with CLOB

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, clob

I am trying to create a List from Oracle clob and write the parameters in JSON file.

Here I access the DB and take all the necessary information and assign it to variables"name", "status", "lastSuccess".. etc.

How can I make it a little bit more "Object Oriented" and access all the variables inside (name, status etc.) in order to perform additional checks and calculation of the provided data?

```
public class DataExchangeExecReport{

 public static List<DataExchangeResult> getDataExchangeInfo() throws SQLException, ParseException {
        String query = "select NAME, RUNTIME_PARAMETERS from EXCHANGE_TASKS where NAME like '%[test]%'";
        String dbUrl = FuelConfig.getInstance().getDBURL();
        JDBCManager db = new JDBCManager(dbUrl);
        ResultSet clobQuery = db.executeQuery(query);

        List<DataExchangeResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

        while (clobQuery.next()) {
            Clob clob = clobQuery.getClob("RUNTIME_PARAMETERS");
            String clobValue = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());

            String name = clobQuery.getString("NAME");
            String status = StringUtils.substringBetween(clobValue, "status=", "\n");
            String lastSucessStart = StringUtils.substringBetween(clobValue, "lastSuccessfulExecutionStartTime=", "\n");
            String exception = StringUtils.substringBetween(clobValue, "STACKTRACE", "\n");

            System.out.println("Name :" + name);
            System.out.println("Status: " + status);
            System.out.println("Last Start: " + lastSucessStart);
            System.out.println("Exception: " + exception);
            System.out.println("***************************************");
        }
        return results;
```

I tried to do something with the following constructor and the getters but without any success...

```
public class DataExchangeResult {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String lastSuccessStart;
    private String exception;
    public DataExchangeResult(String name, String status, String lastSuccessStart, String exception) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.lastSuccessStart = lastSuccessStart;
        this.exception = exception;
    }
    public String getName () {
            return name;
        }
        public String getStatus () {
            return status;
        }
        public String getLastSuccess () {
            return lastSuccessStart;
        }
        public String getException () {
            return exception;
        }
    }
```

Best Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Pheonix Why do you say that the Java class/constructor did not work? Seems like a good solution to me. I might suggest a factory method like `DataExchangeResult.fromClob(clob)`. You could do all your validation in either that factory method or the constructor. But why didn't it work?

Comment: @jeff - I have no idea. I cant access the getters from anywhere in the code. Thats why I said that its not working for me.

Comment: You are never adding to your results list. What specifically are you observing? Do you get an error? Null pointer exception?

Comment: @jeff - Yes, this is true. When I try adding and then get the first index, the results is: @ 7486b455 . Could you try and show me how would you do the add and get from the list?

Comment: It sounds like you were printing your DataExchangeResult but you did not override `toString`.  The default is to print the hashcode. I recommend you take a quick peek at an example of overriding toString.

Comment: @jeff - It worked! I managed to do it. But i first returned the whole clob and then I sliced it outside the loop with another for loop. Maybe its lame but its working :)